# How to build a proof of correctness in coq for elements_tr

Tags: logic, coq, correctness, proof-of-correctness

I want to build a proof of correctness for elements_tr...

It is actually related to some sort of reimplementation of BSTs with int keys.

Elements_tr is defined as follows:

```
Fixpoint elements_aux {V : Type} (t : tree V)
         (acc : list (key * V)) : list (key * V) :=
  match t with
  | E => acc
  | T l k v r => elements_aux l ((k, v) :: elements_aux r acc)
  end.

Definition elements_tr {V : Type} (t : tree V) : list (key * V) :=
  elements_aux t [].
```

However I am unable to build such proof as I continuously get false = true...
What Am I doing wrong?

```
Corollary elements_tr_correct :
  forall (V : Type) (k : key) (v d : V) (t : tree V),
    BST t ->
    In (k, v) (elements_tr t) ->
    bound k t = true /\ lookup d k t = v.
Proof.
intros.
split.
induction t.
- unfold elements_tr.
  unfold elements. simpl.
  admit.
- admit.
- admit.

Admitted.
```

Bellow is the full code to run...

```
From Coq Require Import String.
From Coq Require Export Arith.
From Coq Require Export Lia.

Notation  "a >=? b" := (Nat.leb b a) (at level 70) : nat_scope.
Notation  "a >? b"  := (Nat.ltb b a) (at level 70) : nat_scope.

From Coq Require Export Lists.List.
Export ListNotations.

Definition key := nat.

Inductive tree (V : Type) : Type :=
| E
| T (l : tree V) (k : key) (v : V) (r : tree V).

Arguments E {V}.
Arguments T {V}.

Definition ex_tree : tree string :=
  (T (T E 2 "two" E) 4 "four" (T E 5 "five" E))%string.

Definition empty_tree {V : Type} : tree V := E. 

Fixpoint bound {V : Type} (x : key) (t : tree V) :=
  match t with
  | E => false
  | T l y v r => if x <? y then bound x l
                else if x >? y then bound x r
                     else true
  end.

Fixpoint lookup {V : Type} (d : V) (x : key) (t : tree V) : V :=
  match t with
  | E => d
  | T l y v r => if x <? y then lookup d x l
                else if x >? y then lookup d x r
                     else v
  end.

Fixpoint insert {V : Type} (x : key) (v : V) (t : tree V) : tree V :=
  match t with
  | E => T E x v E
  | T l y v' r => if x <? y then T (insert x v l) y v' r
                 else if x >? y then T l y v' (insert x v r)
                      else T l x v r
  end.

Fixpoint ForallT {V : Type} (P: key -> V -> Prop) (t: tree V) : Prop :=
  match t with
  | E => True
  | T l k v r => P k v /\ ForallT P l /\ ForallT P r
  end.

Inductive BST {V : Type} : tree V -> Prop :=
| BST_E : BST E
| BST_T : forall l x v r,
    ForallT (fun y _ => y < x) l ->
    ForallT (fun y _ => y > x) r ->
    BST l ->
    BST r ->
    BST (T l x v r).

Hint Constructors BST.
Ltac inv H := inversion H; clear H; subst.

Inductive reflect (P : Prop) : bool -> Set :=
  | ReflectT :   P -> reflect P true
  | ReflectF : ~ P -> reflect P false.

Theorem iff_reflect : forall P b, (P <-> b = true) -> reflect P b.
Proof.
  intros P b H. destruct b.
  - apply ReflectT. rewrite H. reflexivity.
  - apply ReflectF. rewrite H. intros H'. inversion H'.
Qed.

Lemma eqb_reflect : forall x y, reflect (x = y) (x =? y).
Proof.
  intros x y. apply iff_reflect. symmetry.
  apply Nat.eqb_eq.
Qed.

Lemma ltb_reflect : forall x y, reflect (x < y) (x <? y).
Proof.
  intros x y. apply iff_reflect. symmetry.
  apply Nat.ltb_lt.
Qed.

Lemma leb_reflect : forall x y, reflect (x <= y) (x <=? y).
Proof.
  intros x y. apply iff_reflect. symmetry.
  apply Nat.leb_le.
Qed.

Hint Resolve ltb_reflect leb_reflect eqb_reflect : bdestruct.

Ltac bdestruct X :=
  let H := fresh in let e := fresh "e" in
   evar (e: Prop);
   assert (H: reflect e X); subst e;
    [eauto with bdestruct
    | destruct H as [H|H];
       [ | try first [apply not_lt in H | apply not_le in H]]].

Lemma ForallT_insert : forall (V : Type) (P : key -> V -> Prop) (t : tree V),
    ForallT P t -> forall (k : key) (v : V),
      P k v -> ForallT P (insert k v t).
Proof.
  intros V P t.
  induction t; intros H k' v' Pkv.
  - simpl. auto.
  - simpl in *.
    destruct H as [H1 [H2 H3]].
    bdestruct (k >? k').
    + simpl. repeat split.
      * assumption.
      * apply (IHt1 H2 k' v' Pkv).
      * assumption.
    + bdestruct (k' >? k).
      ++ simpl. repeat split.
         * assumption.
         * assumption.
         * apply (IHt2 H3 k' v' Pkv).
      ++ simpl. repeat split.
         * assumption.
         * assumption.
         * assumption.
Qed.

Fixpoint elements {V : Type} (t : tree V) : list (key * V) :=
  match t with
  | E => []
  | T l k v r => elements l ++ [(k, v)] ++ elements r
  end.

Fixpoint elements_aux {V : Type} (t : tree V)
         (acc : list (key * V)) : list (key * V) :=
  match t with
  | E => acc
  | T l k v r => elements_aux l ((k, v) :: elements_aux r acc)
  end.

Definition elements_tr {V : Type} (t : tree V) : list (key * V) :=
  elements_aux t [].

Corollary elements_tr_correct :
  forall (V : Type) (k : key) (v d : V) (t : tree V),
    BST t ->
    In (k, v) (elements_tr t) ->
    bound k t = true /\ lookup d k t = v.
Proof.
intros.
split.
induction t.
- unfold elements_tr.
  unfold elements. simpl.
  admit.
- admit.
- admit.

Admitted.
```

Comment: You're on the right track. When the goal is nonsense you need to find a contradictory assumption, like `In (k, v) []`.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia , thank, you, what sort of command may I use?

Comment: A possible solution here would be the `inversion` tactic.